# How to create interdependent objects in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, schema

I have a schema with two object types that link to each other through a field. What is the canonical way to create them in a mutation?

---

Let's take a simple schema with a `User` and an `Account` object type. The simplest case of interdependency is a one-to-one relationship, where a user has exactly one account and an account has exactly one user.

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    account: Account!
}

type Account {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    user: User!
}
```

How would we the mutations to create a user and an account look like?

My first idea was to use separate `createUser` and `createAccount` mutations and providing the other object's id. But this doesn't work, since the circular dependency requires the other object to be known.

```
type Mutation {
    createUser(id: ID! name: String! accountId: ID!): User
    createAccount(id: ID! email: String! userId: ID!): Account
}
```

We could make the connection field type in one object optional. Then we could create that object with an empty link to the yet non-existing second object, create the second object (with a link to the first), and then go back to the first and update it with a link to the second.

But I want to avoid making the connection field type optional.

The only way I see is to create both in a single mutation.

```
type Mutation {
    createUserAndAccount(userId: ID! userName: String! accountId: ID! accountEmail: String!): UserAndAccount
}

type UserAndAccount {
    user: User
    account: Account
}
```

But now assume we have a one-to-many relationship, where a user can have one *or more* accounts.

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    account: [Account!]!
}

type Account {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    user: User!
}
```

How would we the mutations to create a user and an account look like now?

When creating a new user, we must create a new account. So, we have to use the previous mutation `createUserAndAccount`. I'm assuming we don't want to create more than one account initially, and instead go back and make an update mutation to the user when we create additional accounts.

But when creating a new account, the corresponding user might or might not already exist. It might be the first account for a new user, or an additional account for an existing user. We would want a mutation for both possibilities, to either link the account to an existing user or create a new user with it.

The only way I can see, is to add a separate mutation `createAccount` for creating an additional account for an existing user, while keeping the previous mutation `createUserAndAccount` for creating an account and a new user.

```
type Mutation {
    createUserAndAccount(userId: ID! userName: String! accountId: ID! accountEmail: String!): UserAndAccount
    createAccount(id: ID! email: String! userId: ID!): Account
}

type UserAndAccount {
    user: User
    account: Account
}
```

But let's now look at the general case of a many-to-many relationship, where a user can have one *or more* accounts and an account can have one *or more* users.

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    account: [Account!]!
}

type Account {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    user: [User!]!
}
```

How would we the mutations to create a user and an account look like now?

When creating either object, the corresponding other object might or might not already exist. Again, I'm assuming we initially don't want to link an object to more than one other object, and instead go back and make an update mutation to it when we create additional other objects.

We would want a mutation for both possibilities, to either link to an existing object or create a new object with it.

The only way I can see is, to keep the `createUserAndAccount` mutation like previously for creating both objects at the same time, while adding separate mutations when the linked object already exists.

```
type Mutation {
    createUserAndAccount(userId: ID! userName: String! accountId: ID! accountEmail: String!): UserAndAccount
    createUser(id: ID! email: String! accountId: ID!): User
    createAccount(id: ID! email: String! userId: ID!): Account
}

type UserAndAccount {
    user: User
    account: Account
}
```

---

I recognise this touches on the difficult problem of circular dependencies.

How would you design this API? Would you delete the link in one of the object types to avoid circular dependencies at all cost?